# insertar una imagen en Excel con datatables.js

Tags: javascript, datatables, sheetjs

Estoy realizando una exportación de un Excel, pero debo agregar una imagen de cabecera para el documento, como podría hacer esto he intentado insertando una imagen directamente en la tabla pero en el Excel no aparece y con xlsx.js tampoco he encontrado forma de hacerlo.
aquí estoy practicando lo que intento hacer en mi proyecto real https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-vcfbpq?file=index.js

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    <title>Aqui debe ir la imagen</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 mt-5 bg-body rounded">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped" style="width: 100%">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
              </tr>
             
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jquery y bootstrap -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <!-- datatables con bootstrap -->
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Para usar los botones -->
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Para los estilos en Excel     -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/datatables-buttons-excel-styles@1.1.1/js/buttons.html5.styles.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/datatables-buttons-excel-styles@1.1.1/js/buttons.html5.styles.templates.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
  $("#myTable").DataTable({
      dom: "Bfrtip",
      buttons:{
          dom: {
              button: {
                  className: 'btn'
              }
          },
          buttons: [
          {
            
              extend: "excel",
              text:'Exportar a Excel',
              className:'btn btn-outline-success',

        
              
              excelStyles: {                
                 
                  
                  "template": [
                      "blue_medium",
                      "header_green",
                      "title_medium"
                  ] 
                  
              },

          }
          ]            
      }            
  });
});
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

he buscado en muchos ejemplos y en ninguno se insertan imágenes
así que les agradecería mucho si me pueden ayudar y si no es posible con estas librerías me podrían recomendar otras, gracias de antemano.